# Bot Framework: Pass DialogContext to ContinueConversationAsync Callback method

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm looking for a way to pass the `DialogContext` to the `ContinueConversationAsync` `BotCallbackHandler` method.

For example, when I am inside a childDialog, the `DialogContext dc` in the `ContinueDialogAsync` method of the childDialog shows correctly 2 dialogs on the stack (childDialog[0] + rootDialog[1]).

```cs
public override async Task<DialogTurnResult> ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

I am trying to access the **same** DialogContext from an API call using the `ContinueConversationAsync` `BotCallbackHandler` method.

```cs
await ((BotAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken));
```

When constructing a `DialogContext` as coded below in the `BotCallbackHandler` method, I can use it to start a new Dialog using `BeginDialogAsync`. However, I am missing the *existing* childDialog on the stack which indicates the bot's current context. I am always getting **only** the rootDialog[0] on the stack, but not the childDialog which my bot is currently processing.

```cs
private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   var conversationStateAccessors = conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));
   var dialogSet = new DialogSet(conversationStateAccessors);
   Dialog rootDialog Dialog = new RootDialog();
   dialogSet.Add(rootDialog);
   Dialog childDialog = new ChildDialog();
   dialogSet.Add(childDialog);
   var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);

   //end the most recent dialog on the stack, which should bring the conversation back to the parent root dialog
   var results = await dialogContext.EndDialogAsync();
}
```

My goal is to be able to end the active childDialog which is the highest up the stack, to bring back the conversation to the parent dialog. How can I retrieve this DialogContext in the CallBack method?

Comment: Based on your commentary it sounds like you're calling `dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync` instead of `dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync`, but you've omitted that code. That's kind of the most important part here. Can you please edit your question to show us what you're actually doing where it says "do something with the childDialog on the stack"?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I'm trying to *end* the childDialog (triggered by the proactive message), to bring the conversation back to the parent root dialog. The dialogcontext however in the proactive message shows only 1 dialog on the stack, while inside my childDialog it shows correctly 2 dialogs on the stack (=1st code sample).

Comment: A proactive message is a message that the bot sends to the user that isn't a direct response to a message the user sent to the bot. When you say "triggered by the proactive message" I assume you mean "during the execution of ContinueConversationAsync" which itself is presumably called in response to a request to your bot's special "proactive messaging" endpoint, but that would be a request sent *to* your bot and so it is not itself a proactive message. Anyway, are you saying you want your bot callback to begin a dialog and immediately end it? Why use a dialog at all?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I don't want to *start* a new dialog. The user is already in a childDialog when my callback will be triggered. I try to make the bot callback *end* the childDialog which the user is in currently, which should bring the user back to the parent dialog. The main underlying goal here is: 1/ user is in root dialog 2/ when an external long running back-end process is to be made by the bot, I 'park' the user in a endless looping childDialog 3/ To resume the rootDialog once the long running backend process has finished, I want to end the childDialog, so that the rootDialog is resumed.

Comment: I'm using proactive messaging here as this is the only way the external backend process can 'notify' the bot that the external process has finished, and the bot can continue processing the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for explaining your scenario, but there are still a lot of possibilities about what might be going wrong here since I haven't seen the rest of your bot code. Have you verified that the child dialog does indeed respond to the user on the turns between when it's added to the stack and when you call api/notify (I have to assume your proactive endpoint is api/notify since you haven't said or provided that code)? Is there any chance the long-running task adds the child dialog to the stack and then doesn't save the state until it finishes? Could you be accessing a different state property?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney! The user can indeed interact with the child dialog and it responds well on the BeginDialogAsync & ContinueDialogAsync methods (user receives the child dialog responses). When putting a breakpoint in the ContinueDialogAsync method of the child dialog, I do see both dialogs correctly on the stack. The proactive endpoint is indeed api/notify, the code shown 2nd & 3rd code block are snippets from the this NotifyController.cs. The long running task does not add any dialogs, it purely does some processing outside of the bot logic and then calls the api/notify when it's finished. :)

Comment: All right, well what kind of state storage are you using? Have you tried inspecting the state directly? There will have to be a long process of guesswork and Q&A here unless you show more of your code. The best thing to do may be to email me your project or a minimal verifiable example. Since some parts of your question indicate potential misunderstandings about how dialogs work, you might also consider reading up on the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney, I have sent you an e-mail explaining in more detail, and have attached my sample project code. The state is stored in memory during testing phase, although once deployed this would be in CosmosDB. Thanks a lot - much appreciated!

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney, thanks for checking in, your answer is definitely valuable! Much appreciated! I’m still trying to implement it, to make sure it fully responds to my requirement, I’ll mark it definitely as accepted as soon as I’ve been able to test it fully. I still would like to test if I can make the promptvalidator look for a proactive message, as a proactive message will not be sent by the user, but will come from the bot.

Comment: All proactive messages come from the bot. When you say a proactive message you're just talking about the api/notify endpoint, right? I feel like you still might not be understanding what proactive messages are, but this document should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message

Comment: It's been a week. Are you willing to accept my answer yet?

Comment: I’m still trying to get it functional. So far I’m looking how to start the ActivityPrompt dialog from an adaptive dialog. I’m still trying to understand as well why in my original sample the state I’m retrieving in the /api/notify endpoint is not the same as the one from the dialog context for a user. Is there anything in my sample code where I should have additionally saved state that I missed?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should only have to save state once per turn. But anything you do with your state accessors after that won't get saved into storage, because it will just affect the turn state cache.

Comment: I need to know if you're willing to accept my answer or if you still need more information. Are you willing to accept my answer?

Comment: I am still struggling calling the custom dialog (which derives from the ActivityPrompt class) from an adaptive dialog. Would you have a little sample of how to do this? 
Aside from the ActivityPrompt (which could be a good alternative solution), in the original code shared over e-mail, I already save the state on every turn, but I'm still unable to retrieve the same state from my /api/notify endpoint. Am I retrieving the state in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case sounds like a good opportunity to use [`ActivityPrompt`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/ActivityPrompt.cs). It's an abstract class so you'll have to derive from it. The idea is that prompts already have "retry prompts" built into them, which means the dialog will keep telling the user that it's waiting for one specific thing when the user tries to talk to the bot. In your case, the prompt could waiting for a special activity that only gets sent to your bot when the long-running process ends. This may be more intuitive than trying to manually end the dialog from outside of it.